# how execute function onto different input tags?

Tags: javascript

## **Javascript code**

```
<script>                  
   function disableBtn() {          
       document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[1].removeAttribute("disabled");                       
   }                            
</script>
```

---

## **html code**

```
<form>

    <p>
        <label for="uname">* User Name :</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="txtuname" id="uname" onclick="disableBtn()" value="">
    </p>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <p>
            <input name="username" type="submit" id="submit" value="Change Username" disabled="disable">
        </p>
    </div>
    <p>
        <label for="fullname">* Full Name :</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="txtfullname" id="fullname" value="">
    </p>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <p>
            <input name="fullname" type="submit" id="submit" value="Change Fullname" disabled="disable">
        </p>
    </div>
    <p>
        <label for="address">* Address :</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="txtaddress" id="address" value="">
    </p>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <p>
            <input name="address" type="submit" id="submit" value="Change Address" disabled="disable">
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to add an `onclick` event in each input tag which executes the function `disableBtn`, but I want this code to work on any input I click. I do not want to have to give a number like this :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[1].removeAttribute("disabled");
```

for every input element.

I think I should use this but I don't know where to put it.

Comment: So this input should be come enabled after you click on the input element?

Comment: yes it should remove the desable property and it did that but i want it to be dyname and not to work only on the index i put in like [1]

Comment: hey guys are you trying to solve it or you don't understand my question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Code:***

Change your function to this:

```
function disableBtn(el) {
    el.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector("input").disabled = false;
}
```

And the handler to this:

```
onclick="disableBtn(this)"
```

---

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/dcg8gzqt/

---

***Explanation:***

So now the handler  passes the current element that was clicked to the `disableBtn` function.

That function then...

- takes the clicked element and traverses up to its `.parentNode`
- moves ahead to the `.nextElementSibling`, which is the next `div`,
- then searches inside that `div` using `.querySelector()` for the first `input` it finds.
- sets the `.disabled` property of the `input` to `false`

Comment: thanks thats work fine .
if you don't mind can you tell me how to make it remove the desable property only if i add or remove something from the input tag because this input i used them to display values from database

Comment: @user2270924 Please ask a different question if that is your goal.

Comment: i can't for now as they block me from asking questions for i day because sometimes i cannot illustrate my questions

Answer (score 1):

You want to loop over every input element and add an event? `document.getElementsByTagName("input")` returns an array, so you can use a loop to go over it.

JavaScript:

```
// This is a function which disables an input element
// Notice I used "this" instead of document.getElementsByTagName("input")[some number]
// "this" refers to the input element that was clicked
function disableBtn() {
  this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector('input[type="button"]').disabled = false;                       
}
// Get every single input element
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
  // Loop through the input elements, and add a "click" event
  var input = inputs[i];
  input.addEventListener("click", disableBtn, false);
}
```